# Error while parsing querystring in asp.net core

Tags: c#, browser, .net-core

I tried the following code

var webAddr = "http://localhost:4508?Name=partha&email=partha@gmail.com";

```
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = webAddr,
            UseShellExecute = true
        };
        Process.Start(psi);
```

//this starts the browser
//now i want to parse the querystring

var request = HttpContext.Request;
            var query = request.Query;
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(item);
            }
But when it hist HttpContext it gives error
Systen.Nullreferenceexception

Why is HttpContext returning null when I've given a url?

Comment: What kind of project are you using ?

Comment: Did you read the link?  You need to open a browser like explorer.exe and pass the URL as a parameter.

Comment: The code should open the default browser at the URL specified, works fine in a quick project. Could you post more of the code and the full exception?

Comment: @jdweng not necessary. if you try to execute (win+R) an url, Windows will open the default browser with that url.

Comment: What framework are you using ? This won't work with core

Comment: @Cid You're correct! Same error thrown when attempting this in core. It has been raised as a bug against the latest core 3.0 release

Comment: The process does not have any environmental variables and does not have a method for sending keys like (win + R).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some discussion around this issue being thrown in the .Net Core GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/33714). The suggested work around is to run the following code:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "http://www.google.com",
    UseShellExecute = true
};
Process.Start(psi);
```

The GitHub link contains some good information about why this is and the reasoning for having to explicitly start the process with the `UseShellExecute = true` flag set.

Comment: Wonder why MIcrosoft keeps changing stuff in every new version?

Comment: @ParthaMandayam The reason they discuss on the thread seems to be because `UseShellExecute` has performance issues, but I've not read fully about it yet. Glad it helped, don't forget to mark as an answer :)